# Batch File - Remove Second File Extension

Tags: batch-file, rename

Using a batch file is there a way that I can strip off the .deploy extension from all files in a directory.

For example

```
1.txt.deploy => 1.txt
2.txt.deploy => 2.txt
```

etc

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
RENAME *.txt.deploy *.
```

A more 'fancy' solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%f IN (*.txt.deploy) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"
```

Comment: And could this easily be made recursive through child directories?

Comment: @David: I believe the second option is easiest to transform, just add `/R` after `FOR`.

Comment: Great info. I used this to remove extension like: FOR /R %f IN (*.a!) DO ren "%f" "%~nf" at the command line. The extension I wanted to rename was a!

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1131907/316154 gives a bit more detail about `%~`