# Batch file that will eliminate second extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a folder that I would like to strip the SECOND extension from.  I need a batch file that will do this :

-part1.prt.1 
-sub-assembly.asm.3 
-part2.prt.5 
-part6.prt.3

This is what I need:

**-part1.prt 

-sub-assembly.asm 

-part2.prt 

-part6.prt**

Comment: I tried modifying the batch file listed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978036/change-file-extensions-and-name-at-once-using-batch-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch File - Remove File Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401928/batch-file-remove-file-extension)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO (
 IF NOT "%%~xa"=="" FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpna") DO (
  IF NOT "%%~xb"=="" ECHO(REN "%%~a" "%%~b"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. I used `U:\sourcedir\t w o` to prove to myself that it will work with spaces in the directory or filename.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all files are in this 3 part format, then you can simply use:

```
ren *.* *.
```

This removes the final extension. So will take "part1.prt.1" to "part1.prt", it would also change "other.1" to just "other", so make sure it's what you want to do for all files.

A neat trick, if all of the extensions you want to remove are under the normal 3 character extensions - e.g. like the revision numbers you seem to have.

```
ren *.?? *.
```

Will only work on 2 character or less extensions